# Limit the ScaleGridLines till last point in angular-chart

Tags: angular-chart

Having an issue with the angular-chart.js it does display the grid lines even beyond the chart last point.[image]

you can see the grid drawn even after the last point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution:

Added margin to the class chart-container, need to add this class in angular-chart.css

```
.chart-container {
    margin-right:22px;
}
```

Also ensure canvas has the below class which sets the chart width to 100%

```
.chartWidth {
width:100% !important;
}
```